# Visual SVN client commit solution files only

Tags: visual-studio, svn, visualsvn

I have VisualSVN client integrated in my Visual Studio and I want to commit modified files. The problem is when I right-click on the solution file item in the solution explorer and choose 'Commit', VisualSVN is trying to commit all modified files in my trunk. This is the same problem if I choose 'Commit' from the VisualSVN menu item.

Is it possible to just show the modified files linked with my solution and not all the trunk files?

I know that with AnkhSVN, this works perfectly but I think I missed something with VisualSVN client.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use VisualSvn menu or context menu in Solution Explorer and choose "Show Changes". It could also be that you have fiddled with the VisualSvn->"Set Working Copy Root" option. Set it back to automatic mode if possible.

As VisualSvn uses TortoiseSvn in the background, it works only with folders so if there is a modified file in the folder not belonging to the solution side by side with a modified file belonging to the solution you will see both files.

Comment: What is very weird is that when I try to commit by right clicking on the solution node, it takes all files of my trunk but if I try to commit by right clicking on a specific project, just files linked with this projet are displayed. Have you any idea?

Comment: Ok, I found the problem. By default, when you open a solution and go to Visual SVN menu>Set Working Copy Root... the default is '$(SolutionDir)\' with '.\' for each parent folder to the root. In my case, it looks like '$(SolutionDir)\.\.\.\.\. When you try to commit the solution, the system try to commit all in the path above; my trunk solution. I must set manually the path to remove all the '\.' After that, the solution will be setup to commit only files in the solution folder and sub-folders. I must do this manually for all solution. It's not a big deal because I don't work with 10000 sol...